# A question involving continuity with respect to the product topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let *H* be a nonempty set, $\cdot$ a binary operation on *H*, $\Gamma$ a topology on *H* and $$\varphi : H \times H \to H, \;\; \varphi(x, y) = x y, \;\; \forall x, y \in H$$
continuous with respect to the topology $\Gamma$ on *H* and the product topology $\Gamma_{H \times H}$ on $H \times H$.

Can someone, please, explain me what is the difference between the continuity with respect to the topology $\Gamma$ on *H* and the continuity with respect to the product topology $\Gamma_{H \times H}$ on *H*?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that there is a difference between the two, but that to speak about continuity of a function you need both a topology in the domain and a topology in the codomain. What continuity implies is that for any open set $\Omega\subseteq H$ then $\varphi^{-1}(\Omega)$ is open in $H\times H$ with the product topology.

Answer (score 1):

Given two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, a map $f : X \to Y$ is said to be continuous if the inverse image of every open set in $Y$ under the map $f$ is open in $X$. Notice that to define a continuous map both $X$ and $Y$ must be topological spaces.

Now in your case, a priori there is no topology on $H \times H$. Thus to talk about continuous maps between $H \times H$ and $H$ you must have a topology on $H \times H$. And, the most obvious topology on $H \times H$ is the product topology.

With the product topology on $H \times H$ you can now talk about continuous maps between $H \times H$ and $H$, namely a map $f : H \times H \to H$ is continuous if the inverse image of every open set in $H$ under $f$ is open in $H \times H$ with the product topology.